# When autohotkey inserts a text string into a file, I need the name and path of that file. Can AHK give it to me?

Tags: autohotkey

I use autohotkey to insert a text string into a text file.
How can I store the path and the name of that file in a new variable?

Let's say I use this code for inserting a date/time stamp:

```
::iii::  ; insert a date time stamp
send, ID%A_YYYY%.%A_MM%.%A_DD%.%A_Hour%.%A_Min%.%A_Sec%
return
```

How can I modify my code to store the path and name of the file I am tagging?

Something like this? :

```
::iii::  ; insert a date time stamp
send, ID%A_YYYY%.%A_MM%.%A_DD%.%A_Hour%.%A_Min%.%A_Sec%
path = <code for extracting path>
filename = <code for extracting filename>
return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
::iii::  ; insert a date time stamp
    SendInput, ID%A_YYYY%.%A_MM%.%A_DD%.%A_Hour%.%A_Min%.%A_Sec%{Enter}
    SendInput, % GetFilePath_notepad() "`n"
    SendInput, % GetFileName_notepad() "`n"
return


GetFilePath_notepad(){
    If !WinActive("ahk_class Notepad")
    {
        MsgBox, Notepad isn't active
        return
    }
    ; https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ComObjGet.htm
    Path := ""
    WinGet pid, PID, A
    wmi := ComObjGet("winmgmts:")
    queryEnum := wmi.ExecQuery(""
    . "Select * from Win32_Process where ProcessId=" . pid)
    ._NewEnum()
    If queryEnum[process]
    {
        Pos := InStr(process.CommandLine, .exe,, 1) 
        Path := SubStr(process.CommandLine, Pos+6)
    }
    else
        MsgBox, Process not found!
    wmi := queryEnum := process := ""
    If (Path != "")
        return %Path%
    else
        MsgBox, Path not found!     
}

GetFileName_notepad(){
    If !WinActive("ahk_class Notepad")
    {
        MsgBox, Notepad isn't active
        return
    }
    WinGetTitle, WinTitle, A
    If (SubStr(WinTitle, -9) = " - Notepad")
        FileName := SubStr(WinTitle, 1, -10)
    If (SubStr(WinTitle, -8) = " - Editor")
        FileName := SubStr(WinTitle, 1, -9)
    If (SubStr(FileName, 1, 1) = "*")
        FileName := SubStr(FileName, 2)
    return %FileName%
}
```

**EDIT:**

Insteaf of

```
SendInput, % GetFilePath_notepad() "`n"
SendInput, % GetFileName_notepad() "`n"
```

you can use

```
FilePath := GetFilePath_notepad()
    SendInput, %FilePath%{Enter}
FileName := GetFileName_notepad()
    SendInput, %FileName%{Enter}
```

SendInput is faster and more reliable as Send

Comment: Thanks! I try to use %FileName% as a variable, and write it out with "send, %FileName%" , but nothing happens...

Comment: See Edit in this answer.

Comment: BTW, can your code for "GetFilePath" be modified to work on any text editor, and not only for Notepad?

Comment: In other editors is much easier to get the path of the file, because they can display it as part of their title. Btw, an accepted answer can help other people who are searching for similar solutions and encourage those who are offering help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [WinGet](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGet.htm#ProcessPath) command to get the full path of the currently active window:
`WinGet, path, ProcessPath, A`

**`path`** is the variable in which you store the result of the command.
**`ProcessPath`** is a parameter of the command that tells it which information you want to extract, in this case the process path.
**`A`** means that you want to get the information of the currently active window.

To get the title of the currently active window you use the [WinGetActiveTitle](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGetActiveTitle.htm) command:
`WinGetActiveTitle, thetitle`

`StringTrimRight` is used to remove the *" - Notepad"* part from the window title.

---

You can test your code with this:

```
::iii::  ; insert a date time stamp
send, ID%A_YYYY%.%A_MM%.%A_DD%.%A_Hour%.%A_Min%.%A_Sec%
WinGet, path, ProcessPath, A
WinGetActiveTitle, thetitle
StringTrimRight, thetitle, thetitle ,10
Msgbox, path=%path% `ntitle=%thetitle%
return
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure how to utilze your suggestion. I inserted your code below my second row and used "send, %path%" to show the content of the variable "path", but the path given was the one to notepad.exe, not to the text file I insert the text string into.

Comment: ::uuu::  
send, ID%A_YYYY%.%A_MM%.%A_DD%.%A_Hour%.%A_Min%.%A_Sec% {enter}
WinGet, path, ProcessPath, A
send, %path% {enter}
send, %ProcessPath% {enter}
send, %A% {enter}
return

Comment: Hi again. The two variables %path% and %thetitle% does not give me what I need. %path% gives me the path to the software notepad ("C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe") and not the path to the file I insert my string into, "C:\Users\espen\Dropbox\notes\".  %thetitle%  gives me the window title ("2014-07-30--13-47-15 - Notepad"), and not the name of the file I insert  my string into, "2014-07-30--13-47-15.txt".